# How Can I Get Query Results for a Date Range with a MySQLi prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, datepicker, prepared-statement

I am trying to get data from a MySQLi prepared statement but would like to get data for a date range that is selected with a date picker on top of the form. This worked perfect until I try and add the date range part to it. Here is the code for my form page:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Welcome | Mountain and Alpine Loan Centers</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Mountain and Alpine Loan Centers">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
cal {
display: none;
}
cal.main {
  width: 100%;
    }
cal.main td {
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    font-family: verdana,arial, helvetica,  sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
cal.main th {
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
cal.main a{TEXT-DECORATION: none;}

</style>
<script language="javascript" src="js/date-picker6.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div align="center">
        <img src="../img/Logo4_Black_Red.jpg" height="126" width="266">
        <nav id="nav01"></nav></div>
        <div align="center"><br><br><br> 

            <form action="../includes/test.inc.php" method="get">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
            <table id="cal.main">
            <div id="cal">
            Dates:<br>
            From:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"> 
 <img src="calendar.jpg"  onClick="start_cal('t1','calendar1');";>  
<div id="calendar1" style="position: relative;top: 40px;left: -220px;z-index:1;"></div>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            To:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="t2" name="t2"> 
 <img src="calendar.jpg"  onClick="start_cal('t2','calendar2');";>  
<div id="calendar2" style="position: relative; top: 40px;left: 220px;z-index:1;"></div>
</div></table>

            </br></br>

            Date Set: <input type="text" name="set_date" id="set_date" /><br>
            Result: <input type="text" name="result" id="result" /><br>
            Employee: <input type="text" name="employee" id="employee" /><br>
            Project: <input type="text" name="project" id="project" /><br>
            Source: <input type="text" name="source" id="source" /><br>
            Appointment Date: <input type="text" name="appt_date" id="appt_date" /><br>
            Branch: <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" /><br>
            First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /><br>
            Last Four: <input type="text" name="last_four" id="last_four" /><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br>
            City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city" /><br>
            State: <input type="text" name="state" id="state" /><br>
            Zip: <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" /><br>


            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </tr>
            </table> 
            </form>
        </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for my Form Processing Page:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

session_start();

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['t1']))
$from = $_POST['t1'];
if (isset($_POST['t2']))
$to = $_POST['t2'];
if (isset($_GET['subject']))
$subject = $_GET['subject'];
if (isset($_GET['set_date']))
$set_date = $_GET['set_date'];
if (isset($_GET['set_time']))
$set_time = $_GET['set_time'];
if (isset($_GET['result']))
$result = $_GET['result'];
if (isset($_GET['employee']))
$employee = $_GET['employee'];
if (isset($_GET['project']))
$employee = $_GET['project'];
if (isset($_GET['source']))
$source = $_GET['source'];
if (isset($_GET['appt_date']))
$appt_date = $_GET['appt_date'];
if (isset($_GET['branch']))
$branch = $_GET['branch'];
if (isset($_GET['fname']))
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
if (isset($_GET['lname']))
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
if (isset($_GET['last_four']))
$last_four = $_GET['last_four'];
if (isset($_GET['phone']))
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
if (isset($_GET['city']))
$city = $_GET['city'];
if (isset($_GET['state']))
$state = $_GET['state'];
if (isset($_GET['zip']))
$zip = $_GET['zip'];
if (isset($_GET['monthly_net']))
$monthly_net = $_GET['monthly_net'];
if (isset($_GET['job_time']))
$job_time = $_GET['job_time'];

$query = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT subject, set_date, set_time, result, employee, project, source,
    appt_date, branch, fname, lname, last_four, phone, city, state, zip,
    monthly_net, job_time
FROM appointments
WHERE
        set_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND result LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND employee LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND project LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND source LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND appt_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND branch LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND fname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND lname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND last_four LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND phone LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND city LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND state LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND zip LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND set_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to ."'
    ORDER BY employee");

$query->bind_param('ssssssssssssss', $_GET['set_date'], $_GET['result'],
    $_GET['employee'], $_GET['project'], $_GET['source'],
    $_GET['appt_date'], $_GET['branch'], $_GET['fname'], $_GET['lname'],
    $_GET['last_four'], $_GET['phone'], $_GET['city'], $_GET['state'],
     $_GET['zip']);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($subject, $set_date, $set_time, $result, $employee, $project, $source, $appt_date, $branch, $fname, $lname, $last_four, $phone, $city, $state, $zip, $monthly_net, $job_time);
$rows = $query->num_rows;
$results = array();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $results[] = array(
    'rows' => $rows,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'set_date' => $set_date,
    'set_time' => $set_time,
    'result' => $result,
    'employee' => $employee,
    'project' => $project,
    'source' => $source,
    'appt_date' => $appt_date,
    'branch' => $branch,
    'fname' => $fname,
    'lname' => $lname,
    'last_four' => $last_four,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'city' => $city,
    'state' => $state,
    'zip' => $zip,
    'monthly_net' => $monthly_net,
    'job_time' => $job_time
    );
}
$_SESSION['results'] = $results;
if($results) {
        header('Location: ../test_page.php');
        }else{
        header('Location: ../test.php?error=1');
    }

$query->free_result();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) due to your date range stuff, which is especially bad, since you're properly using placeholders for everything ELSE in the query...

Comment: 1. What kind of column is __set_date__ ? 2. What is the format of __$from__ and __$to__ ?

Comment: @spenibus It's a 'Date' column. The format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @MarcB The date range stuff isn't working anyways. I am open to suggestion please

Comment: and what are the values you're putting in for `t1` and `t2`? And exactly **HOW** is this NOT working perfect? you get an error? wrong results? no results?

Comment: @MarcB The value of t1 I want to be my 'From' date and the value of t2 I want to be the value of my 'To' date. I have a javascript date picker that puts these values in. I also put data into one of the other fields (i.e. 'employee') and I want to see all the data for that 'employee' between the 'From' , 'To' date range. When I try to run it I get sent to the 'error=1' page which is the 'else' for when there are no results found. I know there are results and it's the date range portion that makes it not work

Comment: yes, but what is the value of those fields? if you're doing `date BETWEEN 'Jan 1, 2007' AND 'Feb 3, 2010'`, then it won't work. they HAVE to be mysql date-formats, e.g. `date BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2010-02-03'`

Comment: The format they are input is the same as the column. YYYY-MM-DD. Also There is only one column that has this dates so the From and the To needs to search the same column

Comment: @MarcB  The format they are input is the same as the column. YYYY-MM-DD. Also There is only one column that has this dates so the From and the To needs to search the same column

Comment: then eliminate everything else in the query and focus JUST on the date portion. if you don't get an error from mysql, then the query itself is fine, and your `where` conditions are eliminating all possible records. e.g. you're filtering out everything. selects which return 0 rows are NOT an error. an empty result set is a perfectly valid result.

Comment: Could you do `exit("AND set_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to ."'");` before `prepare()` and show us the output ?

Comment: @spenibus When I add that before the prepare() I get this error 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli::exit()'

Comment: I meant before the prepare() line, not literally before the function.

Comment: @spenibus I get this as output ---- AND set_date BETWEEN '' AND ''

Comment: Did you select dates in the form before submitting ? Because any missing value in the `BETWEEN` clause would certainly lead to failure.

Comment: @spenibus I did put dates in before submitting and used dates that for sure would have results.

Comment: But your `BETWEEN` clause was empty of values. You're not getting those dates in the `$_POST`.

Comment: @spenibus on the form do I have the input type set to 'date' or 'text'?

Comment: No idea, that's something you have to look up in the docs from your datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Your form uses `method="get"` but you retrieve the date values from the POST data, which is unavailable:

```
if (isset($_POST['t1']))
$from = $_POST['t1'];
if (isset($_POST['t2']))
$to = $_POST['t2'];
```

Because of that, the date condition of your query has empty values and fails:

```
AND set_date BETWEEN '' AND ''
```

You should be using:

```
if (isset($_GET['t1']))
$from = $_GET['t1'];
if (isset($_GET['t2']))
$to = $_GET['t2'];
```

Which returns:

```
AND set_date BETWEEN '2015-7-2' AND '2015-7-15'
```

So obvious I completely missed it. And don't forget to bind the values in the prepared statement to avoid sql injections.